# Connection to the oracle, using a sql developer, if the server uses port hacking

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to connect to the Oracle database through Oracle SQL Developer.

But there is a problem: I have no ordinary IP, I have `"ip: 8888"`.

How do I connect? Port Section is busy: 1521.

And when I enter my `"ip: 8888"` in the hostname section, an error occurs! I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Well, `"ip: 8888"` is not a valid IP to begin with. That looks more like a port number or some kind of example on how to specify IP address and port.

Comment: You are right, my server uses port hacking !!! (I understand that the correct address is "ip: 1521: xe" and I'm out "ip:8888:1521:xe")

Comment: you need to replace `ip` with the real hostname or IP address. You can't just write `ip: 8888` And I have no idea what that "port hacking" is you are talking about. Where is the Oracle server running? On the computer where SQL Developer is running?

Comment: What is, 'port hacking?'